# Скрыть / показать текст при щелчке текст в поле

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Имеется поле TextView или EditText, в котором находится надпись "Текст" и рядом в этом же поле размещается иконка глаза.
Как можно на Kotlin реализовать скрытие / показ текста, при нажатии на иконку глаза?
У меня получилось скрыть все поле EditText, а как заставить исчезнуть только текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких целей можно использовать специальное поле где будет нужная вам иконка:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_input"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:labelFor="@id/second_input"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColorHint="#333333"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_input"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="#333333">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_t"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:labelFor="@id/password_t"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textColorHint="#333333" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

вот именно то что вы ищете:

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
app:passwordToggleTint="#333333"
```

здесь вы настраиваете само наличие глаза и его цвет если он есть. Скрыть все поле это не совсем правильно. Можно так же и без `TextInputLayout`. Сетите тип данных которые будут вводиться в поле в xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_visibility_off_black_24dp"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"/>
```

так же добавляете иконку и обрабатываете клик по ней из активности:

```
mPassword.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener() {
            fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                val RIGHT = 2
                if (event.action === MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.rawX >= mPassword.getRight() - mPassword.getCompoundDrawables().get(RIGHT).getBounds().width()) {
                        val selection: Int = mPassword.getSelectionEnd()
                        if (isPasswordVisible) {
                            // set drawable image
                            mPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_24dp, 0)
                            // hide Password
                            mPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance())
                            isPasswordVisible = false
                        } else {
                            // set drawable image
                            mPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_black_24dp, 0)
                            // show Password
                            mPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance())
                            isPasswordVisible = true
                        }
                        mPassword.setSelection(selection)
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })
```

[вот есть пример](https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/password-toggle-android-without-textinputlayout.php) на java, но думаю на котлине перевести не составит труда. Кусок кода выше переведен на котлин средствами студии.

Comment: спасибо большое)